# 2 stdin, One only once, The other many

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I need to prompt the user first for some info one time before I start the game.  The game is the 2nd stdin which then just keeps looping till the end of the game, asking for input, doing its thing, etc. until someone wins.

I can't get the one time vs continuous working:

let firstRun

```
process.openStdin().on('data', (name) => {

    if(firstRun){
      console.log("Please enter your first name");
      Computer.move();
      firstRun = false;
    }

    process.openStdin().on('data', (move) => {
      Human.move(move);
    });
});
```

the problem is I notice that the outside stdin runs, gets a res but then it's passing its res to the inner stdin which I don't want...

I'm sure I'm probably not going about this right but I don't know what else to try.

Let me give you some new code I tried

```
const play = async () => {
  await promptForName();
  await runGame();
}

function promptForName(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log("enter a your name:")

    process.openStdin().on('data', (name) => {
      console.log(`symbol entered: ${name}`)

      process.stdin.removeListener("data", promptForName);
      resolve()
    });
  })
}

function runGame(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.openStdin().on('data', (move) => {
      console.log(`move: ${move}`)

      Human.move(move);
      resolve()
    });
  })
}
```

When I ran this, the first runs ok it seems, second runs but I get no value for `move` and am not prompted for any input either

Comment: I don't think you are doing what you think you are doing.  There is no such thing as multiple `stdin`.  Additionally, where are you getting the `openStdin()` function it is undocumented in the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html)? The only reference I've seen to it is in this question: [Unknown method process.openStdin()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33831978/691711).

Comment: @zero298 Weirdly, process.openStdin() works without any packages.

Comment: right, I tried just stdin and it bombs, so yea openStdin work and under the hood it's just doing a standard stdin.  `openStdn` is documented on the node site but I don't think many know about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only 1 `stdin`.  You should attach a listener to it and then remove it after the first move.

```js
// Keep track of the computer listener
const computerListener = process.stdin.on("data", name => {
    console.log("Please enter your first name");
    Computer.move();

    // Remove it after the first time
    process.stdin.removeListener("data", computerListener);

    // Set up a new listener
    process.stdin.on("data", move => {
      Human.move(move);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`.once()`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_once_eventname_listener).

```js
// Keep track of the computer listener
const computerListener = process.stdin.once("data", name => {
    console.log("Please enter your first name");
    Computer.move();

    // Set up a new listener
    process.stdin.on("data", move => {
      Human.move(move);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm also trying async/await but when I run a second stdin when resolving the first, the second doesn't take user input

Comment: ah! maybe I just need to remove the first, thanks will try this with my async/await

Comment: I am also using openStdn

Comment: @PositiveGuy If you are trying to create a prompt-ish interface, you may want to consider [`readline.createInterface()`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_createinterface_options).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `else`

```
process.openStdin().on('data', (name) => {

    if(firstRun){
      console.log("Please enter your first name");
      Computer.move();
      firstRun = false;
    }else{ 
      Human.move(move);
    }

});
```